# How to find the equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Sorry for my bad English ...
Task: Find the equivalent to the following function $$f(t) = \int\limits_{-t}^{t}{\sqrt[x^2]{\cos(x)}dx}$$
when $t\to 0^+$.
I would be happy if you explain how to do it in the general case.

Comment: I am not sure what $\~0^+$ means here. But it might be helpful to note that your function within the integral is even. That is, $g(x)=cos(x)^{1/x^2}$ has the property that $g(t)=g(-t)$.

Comment: This means that we are looking for an equivalent at the origin zero.

Comment: Well, then the integral will be rewritten with a coefficient of 2 and a zero lower limit, but this does not solve the problem

Comment: Maybe I understand: We are looking for a Taylor series? We can take the $n$th derivative and create a function about $x=0$.

Comment: I do not really understand what the problem is ... (About the "on hold")

Comment: Can you tell us what motivated you to ask this question? Is this an exercise from homework?

Comment: This is a problem with one course on mathematical analysis, there was no solution, so I became interested in how it is solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is clear that
$$
f(t) = \int_{-t}^t (\cos(x))^{1/x^2}dx = \int_{-t}^t e^{\frac{1}{x^2} \ln \cos(x)}dx
$$
is indeed well-defined, since $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2} \ln \cos(x)$ is continuous on $(-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2})\setminus \{0\}$ and can be extended by continuity at $0$ as
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} \ln \cos(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \ln \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right) = -\frac{1}{2}+o(1) \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} -\frac{1}{2}\,. \tag{1}
$$

In particular, we get that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(t) = 0$. Further, since the summand $$\phi(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x^2} \ln \cos(x)}$$ is even, by the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
\frac{f(t)}{t} = \frac{2\int_{0}^t \phi(x)dx}{t} \xrightarrow[t\to0]{} 2 \phi(0) = 2\lim_{t\to 0} \phi(t) = 2e^{-1/2} \tag{2}
$$
the last equality by (1).

Therefore,
$$
f(t) \operatorname*{\sim}_{t\to 0^+} 2e^{-1/2} t\,. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x^2} \ln \cos(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \ln (1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))$$

This step follows as we are exploiting the taylor series of cosine?

Comment: @Mason Yes. And then, using $\log(1-u) = -u + o(u)$.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter: can you explain the rationale? What is not helpful with my answer, and how to improve it?